# C++ template partial specialization with inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

I need partial specialization of the `struct`, but I'd like also use some common functionality. For example, suppose I have the next type:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Foo  
{
    Foo& func0() { /* common actions with A and B */; return *this; }  
    void func1() { /* common actions with A and B */ }
    void func2() { /* common actions with A and B */ }
}
```

Then I want specialize it for one of the template parameters - for example, I want consider special case when `B` is `int`, and I want to preserve `func0` and `func1` behaviour exactly the same as in common `Foo` (or course, `func0()` must return my specialized `Foo&` for `int`), `func2` I want rewrite (suppose that I have more efficient implementation of it for integers), and I also want add `func3()` only for my specialized `Foo`.

Of course, I can simpy write the following:

```
template <typename A>
struct Foo<A, int>  
{
    Foo& func0() { /* common actions with A and B */; return *this; }  
    void func1() { /* common actions with A and B */ }
    void func2() { /* actions with A and 'int' */ }
    void func3() { /* actions with A and 'int' */ }
}
```

but I'd like to avoid copy-paste in `func0` and `func1`.

I also can rename common `Foo` to something like `FooBase` and simply inherit `Foo` from it, but in this case I can't use the common case as

```
Foo<float, float> a;
```

What methods does exist for allow me using both

```
Foo<float, float> a;
```

and

```
Foo<float, int> b;
```

without copying and pasting common `Foo`'s code to specialization?

I'm interested in both c++11 and earlier standard compatibility.

Comment: Piotr S gave a good answer to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444624/how-to-simulate-a-partial-specialization-of-selected-member-functions-based-on-a

Comment: @JayMiller, it's slightly different case - I want not only change base methods for partial case, I'd like to add specific methods in specialized types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work for me.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Foo;

template <typename A, typename B>
struct FooBase
{
    Foo<A, B>& func0()
    {
        cout << "FooBase:func0\n";
        return static_cast<Foo<A, B>&>(*this);
    }

    void func1() { cout << "FooBase::func1\n"; }
    void func2() { cout << "FooBase::func2\n"; }
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Foo : public FooBase<A, B> {
};

template <typename A>
struct Foo<A, int> : public FooBase<A, int>
{
    void func2() { cout << "Foo<A, int>::func2\n"; }
    void func3() { cout << "Foo<A, int>::func3\n"; }
};
```

If you wind up needing the definition of Foo within FooBase, you may need to use the CRTP trick of passing the derived class as a template parameter to FooBase, but for simple things I think the forward declaration is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tag-dispatching:

```c++
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Foo  
{
    decltype(func0(std::is_same<B, int>{})) func0()
    {
        return func0(std::is_same<B, int>{});
    }
    void func1() { /* common actions with A and B */ }
    void func2() { /* common actions with A and B */ }
private:
    Foo& func0(std::true_type)  { func0_common(); return *this; }
    void func0(std::false_type) { func0_common(); }
    void func0_common() { /* common actions with A and B */ }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives answer for initial question, but as I understand, I can't add more than one specialization of `func0()` with this method (for example, if I want also `func0()` for `float`?