# Inheritance of a template class

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
class store  // Very basic class, capable of accepting any data-type and does nothing too much
{
  public:
    store(T value) : value(value) {}
  private:
    T value;
}

template <>
class store<int>  // Inherits all the basic functionality that the above class has and it also has additional methods
: public store<int> // PROBLEM OVER HERE. How do I refer to the above class?
{
  public:
    store(int value) : store<int>(value) /* PROBLEM OVER HERE. Should refer to the constructor of the above class */ {}
    void my_additional_int_method();
}
```

Here I have problem with the inheritance. I do not want to change the name of the base class because the base class serves for the same purpose as all the derived classes (the only difference - derived classes have few extra methods)

Comment: ***"Please add some context to explain thhe code sections (or... it looks llike your post is mostly code; please add some more details"*** So You noticed that?

Comment: You're trying to make a class that inherits, um, itself? What? Is this an attempt at specialisation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27453449/560648

Comment: I know it makes no sense to inherit the derived class itself. My question is how do I refer to the base class?

Comment: @user3600124 As for your _few extra methods_, are these mean to be called from a public interface, or are these meant to be used internally only?

Comment: Extra methods are gonna be public

Comment: @user3600124 So clients need to know the public interface as instantiating some class like `store_int` specifically? You simply cannot introduce new member functions upon template class specialization.

Comment: Actually you can, the specialization can have completely different methods. What you actually can't is to use/inherit the methods of unspecialized template in its specialization (directly).

Comment: @axalis I forgot about the _Mixin Pattern_, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class store_impl
{
  public:
    store_impl(T value) : value(value) {}
  private:
    T value;
}

// default class accepting any type
// provides the default methods
template <typename T>
class store: public store_impl<T>
{
public:
    store(T value) : store_impl(value) {}
}

// specialization for int with extra methods
template <>
class store<int>: public store_impl<int>
{
  public:
    store(int value) : store_impl<int>(value)
    {}
    void my_additional_int_method();
}
```

Comment: That's a very good idea to use a mixin to extend the interface on specializations.

Comment: Marked as the best answer. Can't find any better way around

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give a class the name of a specialized template:

```
template <>
class store<int>
```

what you can do is give it a concrete typename:

```
class store_int : public store<int>
```

or use a `typedef` or `using` statement

```
typdef store<int> store_int;

using store_int = store<int>;
```