# How to call a member function of the primary class template from the member function of a specialization

Tags: c++, templates, member-functions, partial-specialization, class-template

Can I call an unspecialized template method from a specialized one?

This is easy when using inheritance:

```
class SomeBaseClass {
  virtual void DoWork() { /* Do something */ }
};

class SomeClass : public SomeBaseClass {
  void DoWork() {
    // Do something first
    SomeBaseClass::DoWork();
  }
};
```

But is a bit different when using templates:

```
template <class T>
class SomeClass {
  void DoWork();
};

template<class T>
void SomeClass<T>::DoWork() { /* Do something */}

template<>
void SomeClass<int>::DoWork() {
   // Do something first
   DoWork<>(); // Call method from line 8
}
```

My generic DoWork function has a lot of really good code in it that I'd hate to duplicate.  My specialized one just has an extra step that it needs to perform when a specific type is used.

Comment: Move the type independent parts out to separate functions.

Comment: You'd have to say what type it was for, which I guess isn't `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking about this the wrong way.
The solution is not to have your class specialized, but to have your function specialized. What I mean here is to use **tag dispatch**

That is, declare two `private` helper functions in your class named `DoWorkHelper`, one of which is overloaded for the specialized type, and the other not.

The way we do this is to wrap our type in a 'tag' that is basically an empty struct, and then specialize the tag for our type of interest:

```
namespace SomeClassDetail{
template<class T>
struct specialized_tag : std::false_type{};

template<>
struct specialized_tag<int>: std::true_type{};
}
```

`true_type` and `false_type` are essentially [wrappers for boolean `true` and `false`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant). They're nice because they're *types* and not *values* (and when we template we care all about types)

Next, we'll declare our class with aforementioned overloads:

```
template <class T>
class SomeClass {
public:
  void DoWork();
  
  private:
  void DoWorkHelper(std::true_type);
  void DoWorkHelper(std::false_type);
};
```

The idea here is that `true_type` means "Yes, this function is for the specialized version!"

Here's what the definitions look like:

```
template<class T>
void SomeClass<T>::DoWork()
{ 
    DoWorkHelper(typename SomeClassDetail::specialized_tag<T>::type{});
}

template<class T>
void SomeClass<T>::DoWorkHelper(std::true_type)
{
   std::cout << "Specialized DoWork\n";
   DoWorkHelper(std::false_type());
}
  
template<class T>
void SomeClass<T>::DoWorkHelper(std::false_type)
{
    std::cout << "Unspecialized DoWork\n";
}
```

That's it. The specialized version will do its thing, and then call the unspecialized version, and the unspecialized version (for all other `T`), will simply do its thing.

#### [Here's a live demo that demonstrates tag dispatch in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01ac66d373480ea0)

Comment: You could just have a `DoWorkHelperCommon` member function which is never specialized, and a `DoWorkHelper` member function which may be specialized. Tag dispatch looks like it's only complicating things.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40749304/1274747), you can do that indirectly:

```
template <class T>
class SomeClassCommonImpl {
  void DoWork();
};

template<class T>
void SomeClassCommonImpl<T>::DoWork() { /* Do something */}

template <class T>
class SomeClass: public SomeClassCommonImpl<T> {
  // use the default implementation
};

template <>
class SomeClass<int>: public SomeClassCommonImpl<int> {
  void DoWork();
};

template<>
void SomeClass<int>::DoWork() {
   // Do something first
   SomeClassCommonImpl<int>::DoWork<>(); // Call the common method
}
```

Comment: Questionable use of public inheritance here. Is it really true (or should it be true that) that a SomeClass is a SomeClassCommonImpl ?

Comment: Well, depends on the usage. Of course, composition or private inheritance can be used too. Only it will require to re-define the method in the non-specialized template to call the common method.