# How to call a member function of the primary class template from a specialization, without modifying the primary template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, class-template

I am looking for a way to call the primary class template member function from a member function in a class template specialization.
This is similar to the way we can call the base class virtual member function from overriden derived class member function.

```cpp
// Template defintion
template <typename T>
class MyClass final
{
    ...
    void foo() { ... };
}
```

```
// Template specialization for method foo
template<>
void MyClass<MyType>::foo()
{
   ...
   // call primary template's foo() here??
   // MyClass::free(); // Warning: All paths through this function will call itself
}
```

Note: I do not own the code containing the primary template definition, only the template specialization part. I am looking for solutions within these restrictions. There is a similar question [How to call a member function of the primary class template from the member function of a specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41280944/) without these restrictions, and I cannot use the answers there.

Comment: Terminology note: template specialization is not inheritance so `base` in the question title may not be appropriate. You probably meant `primary template`.

Comment: There's no way. The specialization completely replaces the primary template; the primary template is never instantiated with the set of parameters covered by a specialization. You can define a helper method (say, `foo_impl`) that both the primary and the specialization delegate to, and implement the "mainline" work there.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280944/call-the-unspecialized-template-method-from-a-specialized-template-method) Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @konchy. This question is the same as mine, except that I cannot alter the primary template class, so that solution won't work.

Comment: And thanks @IgorTandetnik. I believe you are right, there is no way around this one without modifying the primary template class implementation

Comment: You should give a more complete example of what you want to do. It might be possible by using a subclass of superclass of MyType and giving it a void specialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call your primary none specialized template by using a new type, which you don't have specialized before.

Something like:

```
 template < typename T>
struct MyClass 
{
    void Foo() { std::cout << "PrimaryFoo" << std::endl; }
};

template <>
void MyClass<double>::Foo() 
{
    std::cout << "Spezialized for double" << std::endl; 
    // and now call the primary template
    // simply define a type where MyClass is not specialized for
    struct Dummy;
    MyClass<Dummy>{}.Foo();
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<double>{}.Foo();
}
```

Quite clear that this will not help if you need your primary class to have the same data type as your specialization because it access some data in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean way to accomplish your task. When you're asking

> How do I call `MyClass<X>::foo` from `MyClass<Y>::foo`?

... that's like asking

> How do I call `std::string::size()` from `std::vector<char>::size()`?

It is simply not possible; you are working with separate types. The only thing `MyClass<X>` and `MyClass<Y>` have in common is the name.

If you were allowed to modify the primary template, then you could make all `MyClass` inherit from a `MyClassBase` class (template), and that could contain the member unspecialized member function. You could create a new instance of `MyClass<X>` and call its `MyClass<X>::foo`, but this would only access the data members of this new object.

One possible solution is to inherit from something which uses the primary template:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct MyClass {
    /* ... */
    void foo() { /* ... */ }
};

template <>
struct MyClass<MyType> : private MyClass<void> {
    void foo() { // this is not overriding; it is shadowing
        // ...
        MyClass<void>::foo(); // call primary template member function
    }
};
```

This does solve the problem, but it also means that you inherit all the data members of the `MyClass<void>` (or other) base class.

Comment: You could accomplish the `MyClassBase` by simply deciding that `MyClass` is the base. `template<typename T> struct MyBetterClass : MyClass<T> {}; template<> struct MyBetterClass<MyType> : MyClass<MyType> { void foo() { extra_stuff(); MyClass::foo();  } };` Now use `MyBetterClass<T>` everywhere.